# Objective-c prevent UTF characters in UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, utf-8

I have an app that gets the users name and email address. I want to prevent special UTB characters like ê and wondering how to prevent them? I don't care if the person wants it in their name as it is screwing up the backend.

I want to turn all ê into e. Also any similar. Is there a way to prevent the keyboard to offer those up? Though it doesn't prevent someone from copying a pasting.

Yes, the backend should handle these, but the deliver that did isn't around and I don't want to pay to fix it. Just need to prevent on the client app.

Comment: can you please explain your question in detail?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to prevent the keyboard to offer those up? Though it doesn't prevent someone from copying a pasting

Implement the UITextFieldDelegate method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` to replace any non-ASCII characters with their ASCII equivalents. This will prevent pasting as well as keyboard text entry of non-ASCII characters.